# Displaying a category when editing a post in laravel

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

I am creating a blog in Laravel. I have two tables - posts and categories. 
When i want to edit one post, i have a problem with categories. My post controller is sending categories to the view, i can see them while editing, but i don't know how to set the current category in the select option.
The tables are conected:

```
public function posts(){

    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}

public function category(){

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}
```

Controller:

```
public function edit(Post $post)
{
    $categories = Category::all();

    return view('admin.posts.edit', compact('post'))->withCategories($categories);
}
```

View:

```
<form action="{{ route('posts.update', ["post" => $post->id]) }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
            @csrf
            <div class="form-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Naslov</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input type="text" name='title' value='{{ old("title", $post->title) }}' class="form-control">
                        @if($errors->has('title'))
                            <div class='text text-danger'>
                                {{ $errors->first('title') }}
                            </div>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Kategorija</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <select class="form-control" name="category_id">
                            @if(count($categories) > 0)
                                @foreach($categories as $category)
                                    <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            @endif
                        </select>
                        @if($errors->has('category_id'))
                            <div class='text text-danger'>
                                {{ $errors->first('category_id') }}
                            </div>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                </div>
```

How can i make the category display the current category of the selected post in the option select like i have for title? `value='{{ old("title", $post->title) }}'`

Comment: Also, just a heads up, this was pointed out in another answer, but your `@if(count($categories) > 0)` is unnecessary; if count is 0, the `@foreach()` won't run, so you don't need it. You can use `@forelse()`, as suggested, or just outright omit the `@if()` check there. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show the currently associated `Category`, you can set a default "selected" option based on the `$post->category_id`:

```
<option value="{{ $category->id }}" {{ old('category_id', $post->category_id) == $category->id ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $category->name }}</option>
```

This a simple ternary that sets the `selected` attribute of one of the options based on the `old()` value, or, if `old()` is not set, then based on the value of `$post->category_id`

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the `selected` property of the [`<option>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) element.

```php
@forelse ($categories as $category)
    <option value="{{ $category->id }}" {{ $category->id == old('category_id', $post->category_id) ? 'selected' : '' }}>
        {{ $category->name }}
    </option>
@endforelse
```

A minor change as well in the in you blade template to make use of the [`@forelse`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/blade#loops) directive for less code.

You could also change your controller code a bit:

```
return view('admin.posts.edit', compact('post', 'categories'));
```

Further the [`laravelcollective/html`](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/6.0/html) package might help you a lot in creating forms.